# Testcontainers DockerComposeContainer with Docker Compose version v2.0.0

Tags: docker-compose, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I'm trying to use testcontainers with a `DockerComposeContainer`. My docker-compose.yaml content is this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ordering
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ordering
      POSTGRES_DB: ordering
```

I'm stating the container using the following spring-boot initializer code:

```java
  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      DockerComposeContainer<?> environment = new DockerComposeContainer<>(DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE)
          .withExposedService(DB_SERVICE_NAME, DB_PORT)
          .withLocalCompose(true)
          .start();
}
```

This used to work until a recent update of docker-desktop on MacOS.

Now it throws the following error:

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Aborting attempt to link to container l2whc7cxqkzd_postgresql_1 as it is not running
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.applyConfiguration(GenericContainer.java:812)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:363)
    ... 40 more
```

If I put a break point in the code before it throws the exception and check my running docker containers I see a container with name `l2whc7cxqkzd-postgresql-1`. The difference is the use of dashes instead of underscores in the name. I guess this a recent change in the docker-compose behaviour in regards to project-identifier separator.

My question is, is there a way to use testcontainers with Docker Compose 2.0.0?

My testcontainers dependency version is `1.16.0` and docker desktop version 4.1.0.

Answer (score 6):

One workaround that seems to work is to pass the `compatibility` option to the docker compose command. Like:

```java
static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      DockerComposeContainer<?> environment = new DockerComposeContainer<>(DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE)
          .withOptions("--compatibility")
          .withExposedService(DB_SERVICE_NAME, DB_PORT)
          .start();
   }
}
```

Comment: The above works because the option to use local compose is removed 
.withLocalCompose(true). In this case behind the scenes, Testcontainers launches a temporary docker compose client. Removing .withOptions("--compatibility") should just work as well if local docker-compose not set to true